# Getting path/"unique selector" to HTML object: why it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get path to object that was selected by user. I made a code, but it doesn't work correctly and I have no idea why.

Here it is:

```
var selObj = window.getSelection().anchorNode; //chosen html object
var currentCheck = selObj; //element which name is added to path
var path = ""; //path to element
while (currentCheck.tagName != "BODY") {
    currentCheck = currentCheck.parentNode;
    var addToPath = currentCheck.tagName.toLowerCase();

    //class
    if (currentCheck.className != "") {
        var divideClassNames = currentCheck.className.replace(/( {2,})/, '').replace(/ *$/, '').replace(/^ */, '').replace(/\ /g, '.');
        addToPath += "." + divideClassNames;
    }
    //id
    if (currentCheck.id != "") {
        addToPath += "#" + currentCheck.id;
    }

    //nthchild
    var i = 0;
    var child = currentCheck;
    while ((child = child.previousSibling) != null) {
        i++;
    }
    addToPath += ":nth-child(" + i + ")";

    if(path !== ""){
        path = addToPath + " > " + path;
    } else {
        path = addToPath;
    }

}
```

You can copy it, highlight some text on any website and run in browser console.

I highlighted first few words ("The domestic dog") of this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog) and what I got is:

> body.mediawiki.ltr.sitedir-ltr.ns-0.ns-subject.page-Dog.skin-vector.action-view:nth-child(2) > div.mw-body#content:nth-child(5) > div.mw-body-content#bodyContent:nth-child(9) > div.mw-content-ltr#mw-content-text:nth-child(7) > p:nth-child(6)

Using:

```
$("body.mediawiki.ltr.sitedir-ltr.ns-0.ns-subject.page-Dog.skin-vector.action-view:nth-child(2) > div.mw-body#content:nth-child(5) > div.mw-body-content#bodyContent:nth-child(9) > div.mw-content-ltr#mw-content-text:nth-child(7) > p:nth-child(6)")
```

In browser console returns no elements (browser can't find it).

In firefox there is an option to "Copy unique selector". I used it on object which path I want to get and what I've got is:

```
#mw-content-text > p:nth-child(4)
```

As you see, there is some problem with "nth-child" (my script returns 6, browser - 4). I tried on other sites: everywhere is some problem with nth-child only.

What should I change to make this work correctly?

Comment: Why do you need to get the path ? What do you want to do with it ? If you only want to find which element is selected without worrying about its path, you can just use the onselect event, see here  : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp

Comment: I add a solution for the problem, but the unique selector is an interesting talk.

If the objective is to get the unique selector, remember that you can stop in the first ID because this is unique.  If the id is not unique you are not sure that jquery will go to return the good one. As well if you use :nth-clid you can remove the class elements because is redundant.

Comment: @singe31 I want to save in database text that was highlighted by user and highlight it when he visit this page again. I need path to save position of selected data.

Comment: @RaúlMartín do you know how to get object described by this path without using jQuery?

Comment: Sure document.querySlectorAll 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the text node

```
while ((child = child.previousSibling) != null) {
    if (child.nodeType != 3) {
      i++;
    }
}
```

You add a text node in your count for nth-child and you don't need it. All white space in the HTML, between  tags, create a text node in the dom

More info http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp